# How do I gracefully stop a thread within a spawned/forked process?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Objective:

Create two processes, one for each "automation type". Each process created will run "automation tasks" in threads. So I should end up with 2 processes, each process can have many threads doing work.

**NOTE: In my code below I'm only running one process, simply because it's easier whilst I'm trying to get it working.**

Question/Problem:

I am able to create a process, and inside it I am able to create threads. I can also manage to catch OS signals and gracefully stop the process, but not the threads inside the spawned/forked process.

My question is: how can I also gracefully stop threads inside a spawned/forked process in Python? This should be driven ultimately by the catching of OS signals on the script.

Code:

I've left any commented code in as it may help to show some of my thinking.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import signal
import threading
import time
import sys


def fake_task():
    print("task blah blah...")
    time.sleep(10)


def exit_process(signum, frame):
    global processes

    print(f"Signal {signum} received")

    print("Terminating processes...")
    for process in processes:
        process.stop.set()
        process.terminate()

    print("Exiting...")
    sys.exit(0)


class AutomationTask(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = threading.Event()
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop.is_set():
            # while not self.stop.wait(10):
            fake_task()
        print("stopping task...")


class AutomationProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = mp.Event()
        # self.tasks = []
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        # signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_task)
        # global exit_task
        # exit_task = functools.partial(exit_task, tasks=self.tasks)
        # signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_task)
        # signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_task)

        print(f"Starting process with id {self.pid}...")

        t = AutomationTask()
        t.start()
        # self.tasks.append(t)

        while not self.stop.is_set():
            time.sleep(1)

        print(f"stopping process (pid={self.pid})...")
        t.stop.set()
        t.join()


def main():
    global processes

    p = AutomationProcess()
    p.start()

    processes.append(p)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_process)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_process)
    p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    main()
```

Error:

In the below snippet, notice the lack of "stopping task..." message - my assumption here is that the task is in fact not getting stopped gracefully. Imagine for example it wasn't a print statement and maybe some cleanup code or something.

```bash
❯ python pyba.py
Starting process with id 36925...
task blah blah...
^CSignal 2 received
Terminating processes...
Exiting...
```

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: do you know concurrent.futures lib ?

Comment: This is very convoluted, what is the general problem you are trying to solve? For instance, do you need to run two things in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Of cource `print("stopping task...")` and `print(f"stopping process (pid={self.pid})...")` message will not be printed most of the time. Because when you do `process.stop.set()` you send notification to the child process. But the child process can be sleeping because of this `while not self.stop.is_set(): sleep(1)`. so when you send notification from parent process to child process, child proc get this notification but it is sleeping that's why child proc will wait at least 1 second to check this notification. However you are killing the child process with this command `process.terminate()` without waiting the child process checking the notification with this `while not self.stop.is_set()`. Same concept valid for `while not self.stop.is_set(): fake_task()` in subthread. How do we solve this ? We can use `Event()` object that we can be sure that child process gracefully shutdown

Here the code :

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import signal
import threading
import time
import sys


def fake_task():
    print("task blah blah...")
    time.sleep(10)


def exit_process(signum, frame):
    global processes

    print(f"Signal {signum} received")

    print("Terminating processes...")
    for process in processes:
        process.stop.set()
        event_to_parent.wait()
        process.terminate()

    print("Exiting...")
    sys.exit(0)


class AutomationTask(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = threading.Event()
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop.is_set():
            # while not self.stop.wait(10):
            fake_task()
        print("stopping task...")


class AutomationProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self,event_to_parent):
        self.stop = mp.Event()
        self.event_to_parent=event_to_parent
        # self.tasks = []
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        # signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_task)
        # global exit_task
        # exit_task = functools.partial(exit_task, tasks=self.tasks)
        # signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_task)
        # signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_task)

        print(f"Starting process with id {self.pid}...")

        t = AutomationTask()
        t.start()
        # self.tasks.append(t)

        while not self.stop.is_set():
            time.sleep(1)

        print(f"stopping process (pid={self.pid})...")
        t.stop.set()
        t.join()
        self.event_to_parent.set()


def main():
    global processes

    p = AutomationProcess(event_to_parent)
    p.start()

    processes.append(p)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_process)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_process)
    p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_to_parent=mp.Event()
    processes = []
    main()
```

By the way i used `SIGTERM` signal from another session and i did'nt use `Ctrl-c` from terminal because `Ctrl-c` signal will be send to all process group. So if you use `Ctrl-c` signal, child process will be killed immediately and `event_to_parent.wait()` cause a deadlock situation.